# Using single entry file for react native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, cross-platform

I am attempting to use a single entry file for android and iOS in a React Native app.

I have followed a few tutorials and have ended up with the following:

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

export default class Main extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
        <Text>Hello world! from both IOS and Android</Text>
      );
   }
}
```

index.ios.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import {Main} from './index';


AppRegistry.registerComponent('Main', () => Main);
```

I end up with the following error:

`Element type is invalid: expected a string(for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.`

If I remove the curly braces from Main in the import statement it says '...but got: object' so I feel like it's something to do with my exporting/importing but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting your `Main` component as:

```
export default class Main extends Component {
```

but importing as:

```
import {Main} from './index';
```

The `default export` should be imported as:

```
import Main from './index';
```

If you use default export, you must import like this. If this doesn't work, there must be another problem in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. If I remove the braces, I have the same error but it says 'object' instead of 'undefined'. Any ideas as to what else might be causing the problem? I can post other relevant code if need be.

Comment: Can you paste the whole message?

Comment: Ok I got it to work actually (after about two hours). I moved index.js to no longer be in the same directory as index.ios.js and index.android.js. I moved it into a subdirectory and then changed import statement to import Main from './src/app' and it started working. I don't understand why?

Comment: I would need to see the whole folder structure to say for sure. But it sounds like the relative import path, which is `./index` in your code above, didn't match the imported component anymore.

Answer (score 0):

React Native tries to import based on platform. For example, if you have `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` in the same folder, React Native will bundle `index.ios.js` only if it is bundling for ios. It is possible that when you import from `./index`, React Native is revolving the path with `index.ios.js` instead of `index.js` because you are bundling for ios.

If you are curious enough, you can try to `console.log` the content of the imported module, e.g. `console.log(Main)` to see what is actually getting imported.